React Native Expo Azure Authentication Custom Redirect URI not Working on Android Expo Go App
The custom redirect URI works fine on iPhone Expo Go, but on Android Expo Go, it gets stuck after entering credentials and clicking the Microsoft sign-in button. Even though I'm using the same
redirect URI, it's not working on Android. I'm wondering if there's a specific way to add custom URIs in my Expo Go app that I'm missing.
This is my sample Microsoft Login.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser'
import * as AuthSession from "expo-auth-session"
import LoginPage from './Login'
import LandingPage from './LandingPage'
import { Platform } from 'react-native'


const tenetID = 'TENENTID'
const clientID ='CLIENTID'

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession()

export default function OfficeSignIn(props: any) {
  const { navigation } = props

  const [discovery, $discovery]: any = useState({})
  const [authRequest, $authRequest]: any = useState({})
  const [authorizeResult, $authorizeResult]: any = useState({})


  const scopes = ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'] 
  const domain = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenetID}/v2.0`

  const redirectUrl = 'myapp://redirect'; 

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSession = async () => {
      const d = await AuthSession.fetchDiscoveryAsync(domain);
      console.log("Discovery fetched:", d);


      const authRequestOptions: AuthSession.AuthRequestConfig = {
        prompt: AuthSession.Prompt.Login,
        responseType: AuthSession.ResponseType.Code,
        scopes: scopes,
        usePKCE: true,
        clientId: clientID,
        redirectUri: redirectUrl,
      }

      
      const authRequest = new AuthSession.AuthRequest(authRequestOptions)
      $authRequest(authRequest)
      $discovery(d)

    }
    getSession()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Checking for authorization result...");
    const getCodeExchange = async () => {
      const tokenResult = await AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync(
        {
            code: authorizeResult.params.code,
            clientId: clientID,
            redirectUri:redirectUrl,
            extraParams: {
              code_verifier: authRequest.codeVerifier || "",
            },
          },
          discovery
      )

      const { accessToken, refreshToken, issuedAt, expiresIn } = tokenResult
    
      

      const response = await fetch(`https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      })
      const responseJson = await response.json()
      console.log('respons',responseJson);
    
      

      return navigation.navigate('CategoryListing')
    }

    if(authorizeResult && authorizeResult.type == 'error') {
      console.error('Error:', authorizeResult);

    }

    if(authorizeResult && authorizeResult.type == 'success') { 
      getCodeExchange()
    }
    
  }, [authorizeResult, authRequest])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {authRequest && discovery ? (
        <View >
          {authorizeResult.type === 'success' ? (
            <LandingPage />
          ) : (
            <LoginPage
              handleLogin={async () => {
                const authorizeResult = await authRequest.promptAsync(discovery);
                $authorizeResult(authorizeResult);
                console.log("Authorize Result:", authorizeResult);
              }}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
})

This is my app.json

{
"expo": {
"name": "myapp",
"slug": "myapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/icon.png",
"userInterfaceStyle": "light",
"splash": {
"image": "./assets/splash.png",
"resizeMode": "contain",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"assetBundlePatterns": \[
"\*\*/\*"
\],
"ios": {
"supportsTablet": true
},
"android": {
"adaptiveIcon": {
"foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
}
},
"web": {
"favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
},
"scheme":"myapp"
}
}

Is there are any additional configurations needed in your app.json file for Android compatibility of Expo Go App. Additionally, exploring alternative methods for handling custom URIs in Expo Go, such as deep linking or universal linking, could potentially provide a solution for the issue I'm encountering.
